# Why `List[B]` is not a subtype of `Seq[L]` when `class B extends A` and `L <: A`?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Having:

```
class A
class B extends A
```

It is correct to write:

```
val foo: Seq[A] = List[B](new B)
```

What do I miss while having an error in?

```
def bar[L <: A](): Seq[L] = List[B](new B)
```

Error:

```
[error]  found   : List[B]
[error]  required: Seq[L]
[error]     def t[L <: A](): Seq[L] = List[B](new B)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signature of your `bar` method is essentially saying, tell me some subtype of `A` and I'll give you a sequence of things of that type. There are potentially a lot of subtypes of `A` that `B` is not a subtype of (i.e., all of them in this case), so implementing such a method as `List[B](new B)` isn't going to work.

More concretely: suppose your code compiled, and then I wrote the following:

```
class NotB extends A {
  def doSomething(): Unit
}

bar[NotB]().head.doSomething()
```

This would also have to compile, but it wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: He stoops to concretize.