# How to return multiple variants of HList from a function?

Tags: scala, shapeless

Having

```
class A
class B extends A
class C extends A
class Container[+L <: HList](l: L)
```

what is *[shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) way* to code as follows?:

```
def foo[L <: HList](a: A): Container[L] = a match {
  case (b: B) => new Container(1 :: "a" :: HNil)
  case (c: C) => new Container(1.0 :: HNil)
  case _ => new Container(HNil)
}
```

and then to use it in a way:

```
val l1: Container[Int :: String :: HNil] = foo(new B)
val l2: Container[Double :: HNil] = foo(new C)
val l3: Container[String :: HNil] = foo(new C) // Compile-time error
```

NOTE that the way above is principally incorrect because of reasons similar to ones described at "[Why `List[B]` is not a subtype of `Seq[L]` when `class B extends A` and `L <: A`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216878/why-listb-is-not-a-subtype-of-seql-when-class-b-extends-a-and-l-a)".

Comment: What do you intend with "shapeless"?!

Comment: @VincenzoMaggio I added a tag concerned to the library. It is https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless. Clarified it in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use shapeless' polymorphic functions for this:

```
// Base case
class LowPrioFoo extends Poly1 {
  implicit def default[X] = at[X] { _ => new Container(HNil) } 
}

// Specific cases
object foo extends LowPrioFoo {
  implicit def atB = at[B] { _ => new Container(1 :: "a" :: HNil) }
  implicit def atC = at[C] { _ => new Container(1.0 :: HNil) }
}
```

Now you can call the function `foo` on whatever you need:

```
val x = foo(new A): Container[HNil]
val y = foo(new B): Container[Int :: String :: HNil]
val z = foo(new C): Container[Double :: HNil]
```

This is essentially the same than you did, but it is encapsulated by `foo` (and interfaces nicer with shapeless). This way you can make sure no unintended conversion happens.

**ADDENDUM**

As @MilesSabin pointed out, there is not much use for shapeless' polymorphic functions, if the value of the argument is not used. A simple type class based solution is probably better. Such a solution is given as follows:

```
trait Foo[T] {
  type R
  def result: R
}

trait LowPrioFoo {
  implicit def default[X] = new Foo[X] {
    type R = Container[HNil]
    val result = new Container(HNil)
  }
}

object Foo extends LowPrioFoo {
  implicit val bFoo = new Foo[B] {
    type R = Container[Int :: String :: HNil]
    val result = new Container(1 :: "a" :: HNil)
  }
  implicit val cFoo = new Foo[C] {
    type R = Container[Double :: HNil]
    val result = new Container(1.0 :: HNil)
  }
}

def foo[A](x: A)(implicit f: Foo[A]): f.R = f.result
```

Note that this is already very close to the inner workings of `Poly`. Compare trait `Foo` to traits [`CaseAux` and `Poly#Case`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/poly.scala) which model parameters as `HList` and allow `result` to depend on the actual value. This makes `Foo` a special case of these type classes.

Comment: +1, I'd written up almost exactly the same answer. One minor point: I'd suggest being explicit about the fact that you're ignoring the function argument by using either `at[B](_ => ...)` or even importing `Function.const` and then `at[B](const(...))`.

Comment: If Poly0 doesn't work for this case (ie. no args) then you should probably send a bug report (or a pull request ;-) in my direction.

Comment: @MilesSabin I don't see how `Poly0` can help us here. We want the function to have an argument but it's result to be constant.

Comment: @gzm0 My mistake. But in that case, since the argument is being used only for its type, I would recommend reworking this as a vanilla type class, with instances for `A`, `B` and default ... `Poly` really isn't adding anything here.

Comment: @MilesSabin There you go

Answer (score 0):

Finally understood the problem essence... Seems like as follows:

```
implicit def fromA(a: A): Container[HNil] = new Container(HNil)
implicit def fromB(b: B): Container[Int :: String :: HNil] = new Container(1 :: "a" :: HNil)
implicit def fromC(c: C): Container[Double :: HNil] = new Container(1.0 :: HNil)
```

Then it is eligible to write:

```
val l1: Container[Int :: String :: HNil] = new B
val l2: Container[Double :: HNil] = new C
// val l3: Container[String :: HNil] = new C // Compile-time error
val l4: Container[HNil] = new A
```

Any better solutions are welcome.